# Was a deal made with Warner Bros so that Peter Porker can do the things he does?

Tags: character, spider-man-into-the-spider-verse

In the movie [Spider-Man: Into the Spider-Verse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spider-Man:_Into_the_Spider-Verse) there is this spider-man character called Peter Porker, who is an alternate funny cartoon version of Spider-Man:

[image: peter-porker]

He does things and says things closely to what the Looney Tunes cartoon character [Porky Pig](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Porky_Pig) does and says.

In one scene he even says "That's all Folks!", and some other Spider-man asks "Is he allowed to say that? Legally?".

So my question is:

**Was a deal made with Warner Bros so that Peter Porker can do the things he does? If so, what kind of deal?**

Comment: I think it's just a parody, usually they won't bother to get permission for parody far as I know

Comment: @Vishwa I just thought since it's Marvel and Warner Bros, and counting their rivalry  it would need permission of sorts...

Comment: While I think its a valid question, my guess is that Vishwa is right considering that while there was a notable inclusion of Star Wars references and imagery within the MCU following Disney's acquisition of both LFilm and Marvel Studios, the DC Arrowverse is also peppered with references despite being (arguably) the main rival. But as they only reference the films (as opposed to the appearance of SW Merch in the MCU) it seems to be fair game as long as the only intention is to reverentially 'omage' the material..

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Well, well. THAT'S ALL FOLKS is a trademark.
Check this - [Trademark Details](https://trademarks.justia.com/736/90/that-s-all-73690013.html)

However you can see what the trademark limitations are:

> International Class 025 - Clothing, footwear, headgear. - Clothing,
>   footwear, headgear.
>
> Mark Drawing 1000 - Typeset: Word(s)/letter(s)/number(s) Typeset

But this is a visual trademark which means you can not replicate that sentence in that font on wearable merchandise.

However, there is nothing stopping anyone from saying it. 
And, also, given it was done in good taste, I don't think WB would have had a major issue with it.